# Developing real-time navigation App using QGIS API?

Tags: qgis, c++, navigation, real-time

I want to develop a navigation application based on QGIS using C++, for live tracking. I think it is quite normal for GIS to do such things, especially QGIS as it is a very mature GIS platform. But after I searched these key words on gis.stackexchange and osgeo-org, it seems that nobody has developed such an application.

I'm novice for GIS, So I came here looking for help. The application I want has these features:

1. Vector images can be symbols for target. e.g. I drive from NY to LA, a vector image(.svg/.eps) stands for me.
2. Real-time displaying. It is necessary to display with the real-time data for real time positioning.
3. The track should be shown on the map.

I seek anything about how to do such a thing  e.g. websites, examples etc.

Comment: If you have QtMobility support enabled in your QGIS build (it's the cmake option `WITH_QTMOBILITY` if you compile yourself) you will have access to real-time GPS location and IIRC there appears a plugin that is able to show a track and the current position and update the screen extent. [QGIS for Android](http://qgis.org/downloads/android/qgis-debug-latest.apk) has this already built-in.

Comment: You mean GPS plugin meets my needs, and I can refer to the GPS process to achieve my program, Is this mean that I can find solutions in QGIS source code?